# $SwitchMap$ error after decompile

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to decompile a jar file and when I do I get these weird things inside of switch statements.

```
private String getRawToolName()

switch (1.$SwitchMap$org$bukkit$Material[getItem().getType().ordinal()])
{
case 1: 
  return "Diamond Axe";
case 2: 
  return "Diamond Pickaxe";
case 3: 
  return "Diamond Hoe";
case 4: 
  return "Diamond Shovel";
case 5: 
  return "Diamond Sword";
case 6: 
  return "Golden Axe";
case 7:
```

If anyone knows a decompiler that does not do this or a way to get around this, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It usually happens when you decompile a switchcase of an Enum type.

Answer (score 5):

Simply changing `switch (1.$SwitchMap$org$bukkit$Material[getItem().getType().ordinal()])` to `getItem().getType().ordinal()` fixes it in the similar cases I've encountered.  Seems to be something about the way it decompiles switches, but you can figure out what the original was.

Comment: Thanks, @Perkins. That just removed error for me. Ca you explain something more in this, like this kind of statements are defined while compiling the project to lib? Or this is an effect when we  decompile the lib to java  ?

Comment: It's a decompiler artifact; as near as I can tell, the java compiler optimizes the switch into a map containing where to jump.  The decompiler sees this, and recreates the pseudo-source code for the static jump table, rather than the original switch statement.  I'm not an expert on the internals of java bytecode, so that's probably not a very nuanced answer.  You can see it for yourself by compiling a simple class with a switch and then decompile it, what you get back won't be exactly the original.

Comment: Thanks, @Perkins. I will also share my thoughts if I can put  some more lights on this.... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/) should decompile these correctly, as should [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/).

Comment: All kinds of errors. I actually think that the first decompiler was better.

Comment: Feel free to submit bug reports.  Also, give [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) a shot.

Comment: I need to decompile a jar file, that one only does specific classes.

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as a perfect decompiler.  You'll probably have the best results using a combination.